# Boost-graph: Unclear Exception in Implementation of Dijkstra's algorithm

Tags: c++, boost-graph

I am trying to implement a directed graph in order to compute the shortest path by means of Dijkstra's algorithm. In order to do this I look at the example provided by the boost website and try to apply what is done in the example. The graph that I try to implement has more than 15k nodes and 50k of edges. The code of the example provided on the website looks similar to:

```
typedef adjacency_list < listS, vecS, directedS, no_property, property <edge_weight_t, int > > graph_t;
typedef graph_traits < graph_t >::vertex_descriptor vertex_descriptor;
typedef std::pair<int, int> Edge;
const int num_nodes = 5;

enum nodes { A, B, C, D, E };
char name[] = "ABCDE";

Edge edge_array[] = { Edge(A, C), Edge(B, B), Edge(B, D), Edge(B, E),
Edge(C, B), Edge(C, D), Edge(D, E), Edge(E, A), Edge(E, B)
};
int weights[] = { 1, 2, 1, 2, 7, 3, 1, 1, 1 };

int num_arcs = sizeof(edge_array) / sizeof(Edge);
graph_t g(edge_array, edge_array + num_arcs, weights, num_nodes);
property_map<graph_t, edge_weight_t>::type weightmap = get(edge_weight,   g);
std::vector<vertex_descriptor> p(num_vertices(g));
std::vector<int> d(num_vertices(g));
vertex_descriptor s = vertex(A, g);

dijkstra_shortest_paths(g, s, predecessor_map(boost::make_iterator_property_map(p.begin(), get(boost::vertex_index, g))).distance_map(boost::make_iterator_property_map(d.begin(), get(boost::vertex_index, g))));
std::cout << "distances and parents:" << std::endl;
graph_traits < graph_t >::vertex_iterator vi, vend;
for (boost::tie(vi, vend) = vertices(g); vi != vend; ++vi) {
std::cout << "distance(" << name[*vi] << ") = " << d[*vi] << ", ";
std::cout << "parent(" << name[*vi] << ") = " << name[p[*vi]] << std::
  endl;
}
```

Using this to implement my own graph results in:

```
typedef adjacency_list < listS, vecS, directedS, no_property, property < edge_weight_t, int > > MyGraph;
typedef graph_traits < MyGraph >::vertex_descriptor vertex_descriptor;
typedef std::pair<int, int> Edge;
```

// edge_array is filled. Assume that it works correct.

```
int num_arcs = sizeof(edge_array) / sizeof(Edge);//<-- Cause of the error
MyGraph Graph(edge_array, edge_array + num_arcs, weights, num_nodes);//<-- Exception is raised. 
property_map<MyGraph, edge_weight_t>::type weightmap = get(edge_weight,   Graph);

std::vector<vertex_descriptor> p(num_vertices(Graph));
std::vector<int> d(num_vertices(Graph));
vertex_descriptor s = vertex(A, Graph);
```

There where the arrow was commented is the cause of the error which occurs at the line thereafter.  There is no error outputed other than *Unhandled exception at 0x012BA9A9 in celfpp.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00434000.*

In case of using two edge_arrays, one used from the example and the other of my own. In case of exectuing the code:

```
int num_arcs = sizeof(example_edge_array) / sizeof(Edge);
graph_t g(edge_array, edge_array + num_arcs, weights, num_nodes);
```

The code does not encounter an exception. To me it is not clear why and I assume that this is not the way to solve my problem. However, it does provides a suggestion of what causes the problem.

Is there anyone whom might have a suggestion how I could solve this?

EDIT (1):

I have found that in the following remains m_value remains undefined:

```
template <class Tag, class T, class  
Base = no_property>
struct property {
typedef Base next_type;
typedef Tag tag_type;
typedef T value_type;
property(const T& v = T()) : m_value(v) { }
property(const T& v, const Base& b) : m_value(v), m_base(b) { }
// copy constructor and assignment operator will be generated by compiler

T m_value;
Base m_base;
};
```

Comment: Step through with your debugger to identify the source of the problem. `0xC0000005` usually indicates there's a `nullptr` dereferenced. I'd suspect some out of bounds access in one of these lines: _`std::cout << "distance(" << name[*vi] << ") = " << d[*vi] << ", ";`_.

Comment: I will have a look at it. However, at the line of code after defining num_arcs an exception is raised and the program is not ran further and thus the code of line that you mention is never executed.

Comment: @Clifford I've looked at it. You need to make it a SSCCE. We can't make heads or tails of that patchwork puzzle